# Swtich browsers in Karate

Tags: karate

I am new to Karate UI automation, stuck with an issue and need advice on how to proceed.

I have a test scenario which is a 3 step process

1. User A logs in and fills up a form
2. User B logs in with a different browser and approves the application
3. User A(already logged in) in step 1 can view that his application is accepted

The e2e test snippet is as follows:

```
Scenario: E2E - User agreement acceptance
   #1 USER A logs in and fills agreement form
     When def userA_create_agreement = call read('./../Features/CreateAgreement.feature') { shared_agrname: '#(SharedAgreementName)' }

   #2 USER B retrieve above agmt and approves it 
    When def userB_read_agreement = call read('./../Features/ReadAndApprove.feature') { shared_agrname: '#(SharedAgreementName)' }
    
   #3 USER A confirms acceptance
    When def userA_confirm_acceptance = call read('./../Features/ConfirmAcceptance.feature') { shared_agrname: '#(SharedAgreementName)' }
```

Each of the 'called' feature files - CreateAgreement.feature, ReadAndApprove.feature, ConfirmAcceptance.feature have the following background section

```
Background: 
    * configure driver = { type: '#(drivertype)', executable: '#(driverpath)'}

Scenario: 
    Given driver agreementmanager_url
    .....
    .....
```

For step 1 and 3 the drivertype and driverpath is chrome
and for step 2 its firefox.  User A and B cannot be logged in at the same time with the same browser. This is by design.

With the above way currently, each of the steps invokes a new browser instance and runs the tests rightly so because I am invoking the driver every time in each of the called feature files. What I am looking for is to be able to switch between the browsers and continue running without needing to invoke a new instance in each feature file if its not needed.

So

```
Step 1 - User A logs in and registers using Chrome
Step 2 - User B logs in and approves using Firefox
Step 3 - Switches back to browser instance of step 1 with User A(who is already logged), views the update of acceptance.
```

I was wondering if this was possible using Karate? I read the documentation and we have switchPage() that switches between tabs of the same browser but is there a way we can switch browers without having the need to relaunch a new instance and login again?

Any advice or help in how to achieve this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your scenario to not have 2 browsers open at the same time. You can try this sequence that should switch from Chrome to Firefox:

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome' }
* driver 'https://github.com/login'
* driver.quit()
* configure driver = { type: 'geckodriver' }
* driver 'https://google.com'
```

So the rule is if you `quit()` you can start a new browser in a flow (0.9.6 onwards).

If you really insist on having Chrome open, maybe you can experiment with the Java API, which gives you more control: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#chrome-java-api

But have you really reached a level of maturity where all the other things you want to test are running trouble free :)

Anyway, to simulate the "logged in" context from the first browser - all you need to do is pick up the cookie values and recreate the cookies later in the test. That is what I would recommend as your test strategy instead of juggling browsers. I would also get that flow to work first before even thinking of switching from Chrome to FireFox, for example I'm not sure if you can even get that to work in Docker or CI. Or are you using a Selenium grid ?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @Peter. Will try what you have mentioned above and update here for the benefit of other users.